# Is primary, secondary, tertiary etc. sorting possible on qooxdoo tables?

Tags: qooxdoo

I can't find any info on this in the qooxdoo documentation (currently on version 4.01 for various reasons), so I'm assuming it is not supported out of the box. Has anyone been able to implement this using qooxdoo, or should I use some other third party table control, or perhaps implement one myself (which I'd rather not)?

Answer (score 0):

I've not seen any implementation of multiple column sorting in qooxdoo yet. What I've done is an implicit multi column sorting with the remote table model, where, if a user selected to sort on column A also sorted on column B, in sql terms "order by A, B"

An implementation for multi column sorting would be very welcome. 
Please join us on https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/ and https://gitter.im/qooxdoo/qooxdoo

Answer (score 0):

(sorry my bad english) Hi.

This is a very old humble example (adapted) of 'my own' multiple column sorting implementation.
Use the table and lists context menus, generate a few sort formulaes, then return to table context menu to select the sort order. (Change the data table for convenience)
Maybe you can get some new idea or some perspective.

[Playground example](http://www.qooxdoo.org/current/playground/#%7B%22code%22%3A%22qx.Class.define(%2522prueba.menubuttonOrdenamiento%2522%252C%250D%250A%257B%250D%250A%2509extend%2520%253A%2520qx.ui.menu.Button%252C%250D%250A%2509construct%2520%253A%2520function%2520(table%252C%2520tag%252C%2520url%252C%2520serviceName)%250D%250A%2509%257B%250D%250A%2509this.base(arguments%252C%2520%2522Sort%2520order%2522)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250A%2509%250D%250A%2509var%2520radiogroup%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.RadioGroup()%253B%250D%250A%2509var%2520btn_execute%2520%253D%2520function(e)%2520%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509this.formula%2520%253D%2520e.getTarget().getUserData(%2522listItem%2522).getModel().formula%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%250D%250A%2509%2509tableModel.setSortMethods(0%252C%2520qx.lang.Function.bind(this.functionOrdenamiento%252C%2520this))%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509tableModel.setColumnSortable(0%252C%2520true)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509tableModel.sortByColumn(0%252C%2520true)%253B%250D%250A%2509%257D%250D%250A%2509%250D%250A%2509var%2520functionGrabarIndices%2520%253D%2520function(model)%2520%257B%250D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%252F*%250D%250A%2509%2509var%2520p%2520%253D%2520model%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509var%2520rpc%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.io.remote.Rpc(%2522..%252F..%252Fservices%252F%2522%252C%2520%2522comp.elpintao.ramon.Ordenamiento%2522)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509try%2520%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509var%2520resultado%2520%253D%2520rpc.callSync(%2522grabar_indices%2522%252C%2520p)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%257D%2520catch%2520(ex)%2520%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509alert(%2522Sync%2520exception%253A%2520%2522%2520%252B%2520ex)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%257D%250D%250A%2509%2509*%252F%250D%250A%2509%257D%250D%250A%2509%250D%250A%2509%250D%250A%250D%250A%2509%250D%250A%2509var%2520win%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.window.Window()%253B%250D%250A%2509win.setLayout(new%2520qx.ui.layout.Canvas())%253B%250D%250A%2509win.set(%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509caption%253A%2520%2522Edit%2520sort%2520order%2520formulas%2522%252C%250D%250A%2509%2509width%253A%2520500%252C%250D%250A%2509%2509height%253A%2520500%252C%250D%250A%2509%2509showMinimize%253A%2520false%252C%250D%250A%2509%2509showMaximize%253A%2520false%250D%250A%2509%257D)%253B%250D%250A%2509win.setModal(true)%253B%250D%250A%2509%250D%250A%2509win.addListener(%2522appear%2522%252C%2520function()%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509lstCampo.focus()%253B%250D%250A%2509%257D)%253B%250D%250A%2509win.addListener(%2522disappear%2522%252C%2520function()%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509btnSel.fireEvent(%2522execute%2522)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509table.focus()%253B%250D%250A%2509%257D)%253B%250D%250A%2509this.getApplicationRoot().add(win)%253B%250D%250A%2509%250D%250A%2509%250D%250A%250D%250A%2509%250D%250A%2509%250D%250A%2509var%2520menuMain%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.menu.Menu()%253B%250D%250A%2509var%2520btnEditar%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.menu.Button(%2522Edit...%2522)%253B%250D%250A%2509btnEditar.addListener(%2522execute%2522%252C%2520function(e)%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509win.center()%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509win.show()%253B%250D%250A%2509%257D)%253B%250D%250A%2509menuMain.add(btnEditar)%253B%250D%250A%2509this.setMenu(menuMain)%253B%250D%250A%2509%250D%250A%2509%250D%250A%2509%250D%250A%2509%250D%250A%2509var%2520commandCampo%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.command.Command(%2522Enter%2522)%253B%250D%250A%2509commandCampo.setEnabled(false)%253B%250D%250A%2509commandCampo.addListener(%2522execute%2522%252C%2520function(e)%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509var%2520selection%2520%253D%2520lstCampo.getSelection()%255B0%255D%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509lstCampo.remove(selection)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509var%2520listItem%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.ListItem(selection.getLabel()%252C%2520null%252C%2520selection.getModel())%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509lstSel.add(listItem)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509lstSel.setSelection(%255BlistItem%255D)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509lstCampo.focus()%253B%250D%250A%2509%257D)%253B%250D%250A%2509var%2520menuCampo%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.menu.Menu()%253B%250D%250A%2509var%2520btnCampo%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.menu.Button(%2522Move%2522%252C%2520null%252C%2520commandCampo)%253B%250D%250A%2509menuCampo.add(btnCampo)%253B%250D%250A%2509%250D%250A%2509var%2520lstCampo%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.List()%253B%250D%250A%2509lstCampo.setContextMenu(menuCampo)%253B%250D%250A%2509lstCampo.addListener(%2522changeSelection%2522%252C%2520function(e)%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509commandCampo.setEnabled(!%2520lstCampo.isSelectionEmpty())%253B%250D%250A%2509%257D)%253B%250D%250A%2509lstCampo.addListener(%2522dblclick%2522%252C%2520function(e)%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509if%2520(!%2520lstCampo.isSelectionEmpty())%2520commandCampo.fireDataEvent(%2522execute%2522)%253B%250D%250A%2509%257D)%253B%250D%250A%2509%250D%250A%250D%250A%2509%250D%250A%2509var%2520menuSel%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.menu.Menu()%253B%250D%250A%2509var%2520btnSel%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.menu.Button(%2522Reset%2522)%253B%250D%250A%2509btnSel.addListener(%2522execute%2522%252C%2520function(e)%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509var%2520selection%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509var%2520indice%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509var%2520bandera%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509var%2520listItem%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509var%2520childrenCampo%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509var%2520childrenSel%2520%253D%2520lstSel.getChildren()%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509for%2520(var%2520x%2520%253D%2520childrenSel.length%2520-%25201%253B%2520x%2520%253E%253D%25200%2520%253B%2520x--)%2520%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509selection%2520%253D%2520childrenSel%255Bx%255D%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509lstSel.remove(childrenSel%255Bx%255D)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509indice%2520%253D%2520selection.getModel()%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509listItem%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.ListItem(selection.getLabel()%252C%2520null%252C%2520indice)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509childrenCampo%2520%253D%2520lstCampo.getChildren()%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509bandera%2520%253D%2520true%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509for%2520(var%2520y%2520in%2520childrenCampo)%2520%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509if%2520(indice%2520%253C%2520childrenCampo%255By%255D.getModel())%2520%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509lstCampo.addBefore(listItem%252C%2520childrenCampo%255By%255D)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509bandera%2520%253D%2520false%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509%2509break%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509%2509%257D%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509%257D%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509if%2520(bandera)%2520lstCampo.add(listItem)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%257D%250D%250A%2509%2509lstCampo.resetSelection()%253B%250D%250A%2509%257D)%253B%250D%250A%2509var%2520btnNuevaFor%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.menu.Button(%2522Generate%2520new%2520formula%2522)%253B%250D%250A%2509btnNuevaFor.setEnabled(false)%253B%250D%250A%2509btnNuevaFor.addListener(%2522execute%2522%252C%2520function(e)%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509var%2520children%2520%253D%2520lstSel.getChildren()%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509var%2520label%2520%253D%2520%2522%2522%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509var%2520auxFormula%2520%253D%2520%2522%2522%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509var%2520indice%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509for%2520(var%2520x%2520%253D%25200%253B%2520x%2520%253C%2520children.length%253B%2520x%252B%252B)%2520%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509label%2520%253D%2520label%2520%252B%2520%2522%2520%252C%2520%2522%2520%252B%2520children%255Bx%255D.getLabel()%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509indice%2520%253D%2520children%255Bx%255D.getModel()%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509%252F%252FauxFormula%2520%253D%2520auxFormula%2520%252B%2520%2522if%2520(row1%255B%2522%2520%252B%2520indice%2520%252B%2520%2522%255D%2520%253D%253D%2520row2%255B%2522%2520%252B%2520indice%2520%252B%2520%2522%255D)%2520%257B%2522%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509auxFormula%2520%253D%2520auxFormula%2520%252B%2520%2522if%2520(this.row1%255B%2522%2520%252B%2520indice%2520%252B%2520%2522%255D%2520%253D%253D%2520this.row2%255B%2522%2520%252B%2520indice%2520%252B%2520%2522%255D)%2520%257B%2522%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%257D%250D%250A%2509%2509%250D%250A%2509%2509label%2520%253D%2520label.substring(3)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%252F%252FauxFormula%2520%253D%2520auxFormula%2520%252B%2520%2522resultado%2520%253D%25200%253B%2522%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509auxFormula%2520%253D%2520auxFormula%2520%252B%2520%2522this.resultado%2520%253D%25200%253B%2522%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509for%2520(var%2520x%2520%253D%2520children.length%2520-%25201%253B%2520x%2520%253E%253D%25200%2520%253B%2520x--)%2520%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509indice%2520%253D%2520children%255Bx%255D.getModel()%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509%252F%252FauxFormula%2520%253D%2520auxFormula%2520%252B%2520%2522%257D%2520else%2520resultado%2520%253D%2520((row1%255B%2522%2520%252B%2520indice%2520%252B%2520%2522%255D%2520%253E%2520row2%255B%2522%2520%252B%2520indice%2520%252B%2520%2522%255D)%2520%253F%25201%2520%253A%2520-1)%253B%2522%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509auxFormula%2520%253D%2520auxFormula%2520%252B%2520%2522%257D%2520else%2520this.resultado%2520%253D%2520((this.row1%255B%2522%2520%252B%2520indice%2520%252B%2520%2522%255D%2520%253E%2520this.row2%255B%2522%2520%252B%2520indice%2520%252B%2520%2522%255D)%2520%253F%25201%2520%253A%2520-1)%253B%2522%250D%250A%2509%2509%257D%250D%250A%2509%2509btnSel.fireEvent(%2522execute%2522)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%250D%250A%2509%2509%250D%250A%2509%2509var%2520model%2520%253D%2520%257Bid_ordenamiento%253A%2520lstFormula.getChildren().length%2520%252B%25201%252C%2520tag%253A%2520tag%252C%2520indice%253A%2520lstFormula.getChildren().length%252C%2520descrip%253A%2520label%252C%2520formula%253A%2520auxFormula%257D%253B%250D%250A%250D%250A%2509%2509var%2520listItem%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.ListItem(label%252C%2520null%252C%2520model)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509lstFormula.add(listItem)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509lstFormula.setSelection(%255BlistItem%255D)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250A%2509%2509var%2520btn%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.menu.RadioButton(label)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509btn.setUserData(%2522listItem%2522%252C%2520listItem)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509btn.setGroup(radiogroup)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509btn.addListener(%2522execute%2522%252C%2520btn_execute%252C%2520this)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509menuMain.addAt(btn%252C%2520lstFormula.indexOf(listItem))%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%250D%250A%2509%2509if%2520(menuMain.getChildren().length%2520%253D%253D%25202)%2520%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509menuMain.addBefore(new%2520qx.ui.menu.Separator()%252C%2520btnEditar)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509btn.fireEvent(%2522execute%2522)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%257D%250D%250A%2509%257D%252C%2520this)%253B%250D%250A%2509menuSel.add(btnSel)%253B%250D%250A%2509menuSel.addSeparator()%253B%250D%250A%2509menuSel.add(btnNuevaFor)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250A%2509var%2520lstSel%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.List()%253B%250D%250A%2509lstSel.setContextMenu(menuSel)%253B%250D%250A%2509lstSel.addListener(%2522addItem%2522%252C%2520function(e)%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509btnSel.setEnabled(true)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509btnNuevaFor.setEnabled(true)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%252F%252FmenuSel.memorizar(%255BbtnSel%252C%2520btnNuevaFor%255D)%253B%250D%250A%2509%257D)%253B%250D%250A%2509lstSel.addListener(%2522removeItem%2522%252C%2520function(e)%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509if%2520(!lstSel.hasChildren())%2520%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509btnSel.setEnabled(false)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509btnNuevaFor.setEnabled(false)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509%252F%252FmenuSel.memorizar(%255BbtnSel%252C%2520btnNuevaFor%255D)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%257D%250D%250A%2509%257D)%253B%250D%250A%2509%250D%250A%2509%250D%250A%2509var%2520grp%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.groupbox.GroupBox(%2522Edition%253A%2522)%253B%250D%250A%2509grp.setLayout(new%2520qx.ui.layout.Canvas())%253B%250D%250A%2509grp.add(new%2520qx.ui.basic.Label(%2522Available%2520columns%253A%2522)%252C%2520%257Bleft%253A%25200%252C%2520top%253A%25200%257D)%253B%250D%250A%2509grp.add(lstCampo%252C%2520%257Bleft%253A%25200%252C%2520top%253A%252020%252C%2520bottom%253A%25200%252C%2520width%253A%2520%252245%2525%2522%257D)%253B%250D%250A%2509grp.add(new%2520qx.ui.basic.Label(%2522New%2520formula%253A%2522)%252C%2520%257Bleft%253A%2520%252255%2525%2522%252C%2520top%253A%25200%257D)%253B%250D%250A%2509grp.add(lstSel%252C%2520%257Bright%253A%25200%252C%2520top%253A%252020%252C%2520bottom%253A%25200%252C%2520width%253A%2520%252245%2525%2522%257D)%253B%250D%250A%2509win.add(grp%252C%2520%257Bleft%253A%25200%252C%2520top%253A%25200%252C%2520right%253A%25200%252C%2520bottom%253A%2520%252242%2525%2522%257D)%253B%250D%250A%2509%250D%250A%2509%250D%250A%2509%250D%250A%2509var%2520menuFor%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.menu.Menu()%253B%250D%250A%2509var%2520btnSubir%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.menu.Button(%2522Up%2522)%253B%250D%250A%2509btnSubir.setEnabled(false)%253B%250D%250A%2509btnSubir.addListener(%2522execute%2522%252C%2520function(e)%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509var%2520selection%2520%253D%2520lstFormula.getSelection()%255B0%255D%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509var%2520index%2520%253D%2520lstFormula.indexOf(selection)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%250D%250A%2509%2509functionGrabarIndices(%257Bid_ordenamiento1%253A%2520lstFormula.getChildren()%255Bindex-1%255D.getModel().id_ordenamiento%252C%2520id_ordenamiento2%253A%2520selection.getModel().id_ordenamiento%257D)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%250D%250A%2509%2509lstFormula.addAt(selection%252C%2520index%2520-%25201)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509lstFormula.fireDataEvent(%2522changeSelection%2522)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%250D%250A%2509%2509selection%2520%253D%2520menuMain.getChildren()%255Bindex%255D%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509menuMain.remove(selection)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509menuMain.addAt(selection%252C%2520index%2520-%25201)%250D%250A%2509%257D)%253B%250D%250A%2509var%2520btnBajar%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.menu.Button(%2522Down%2522)%253B%250D%250A%2509btnBajar.addListener(%2522execute%2522%252C%2520function(e)%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509var%2520selection%2520%253D%2520lstFormula.getSelection()%255B0%255D%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509var%2520index%2520%253D%2520lstFormula.indexOf(selection)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%250D%250A%2509%2509functionGrabarIndices(%257Bid_ordenamiento1%253A%2520selection.getModel().id_ordenamiento%252C%2520id_ordenamiento2%253A%2520lstFormula.getChildren()%255Bindex%252B1%255D.getModel().id_ordenamiento%257D)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%250D%250A%2509%2509lstFormula.addAt(selection%252C%2520index%2520%252B%25201)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509lstFormula.fireDataEvent(%2522changeSelection%2522)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%250D%250A%2509%2509selection%2520%253D%2520menuMain.getChildren()%255Bindex%255D%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509menuMain.remove(selection)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509menuMain.addAt(selection%252C%2520index%2520%252B%25201)%250D%250A%2509%257D)%253B%250D%250A%2509btnBajar.setEnabled(false)%253B%250D%250A%2509var%2520btnEliminar%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.menu.Button(%2522Delete%2522)%253B%250D%250A%2509btnEliminar.setEnabled(false)%253B%250D%250A%2509btnEliminar.addListener(%2522execute%2522%252C%2520function(e)%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509var%2520selection%2520%253D%2520lstFormula.getSelection()%255B0%255D%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509menuMain.removeAt(lstFormula.indexOf(selection))%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509radiogroup.remove(selection)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509lstFormula.remove(selection)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%250D%250A%2509%2509%252F*%250D%250A%2509%2509var%2520p%2520%253D%2520%257B%257D%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509p.id_ordenamiento%2520%253D%2520selection.getModel().id_ordenamiento%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509var%2520rpc%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.io.remote.Rpc(%2522..%252F..%252Fservices%252F%2522%252C%2520%2522comp.elpintao.ramon.Ordenamiento%2522)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509try%2520%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509var%2520resultado%2520%253D%2520rpc.callSync(%2522eliminar_item%2522%252C%2520p)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%257D%2520catch%2520(ex)%2520%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509alert(%2522Sync%2520exception%253A%2520%2522%2520%252B%2520ex)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%257D%250D%250A%2509%2509*%252F%250D%250A%2509%2509%250D%250A%2509%2509if%2520(lstFormula.hasChildren())%2520%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509menuMain.getChildren()%255B0%255D.fireEvent(%2522execute%2522)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%257D%2520else%2520%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509menuMain.removeAt(0)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509tableModel.clearSorting()%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509tableModel.setColumnSortable(0%252C%2520false)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509tableModel.setSortMethods(0%252C%2520null)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%257D%250D%250A%2509%2509lstFormula.focus()%253B%250D%250A%2509%257D)%253B%250D%250A%2509%250D%250A%2509menuFor.add(btnSubir)%253B%250D%250A%2509menuFor.add(btnBajar)%253B%250D%250A%2509menuFor.addSeparator()%253B%250D%250A%2509menuFor.add(btnEliminar)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250A%2509%250D%250A%2509%250D%250A%2509var%2520lstFormula%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.List()%253B%250D%250A%2509lstFormula.setContextMenu(menuFor)%253B%250D%250A%2509lstFormula.addListener(%2522changeSelection%2522%252C%2520function(e)%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509if%2520(lstFormula.isSelectionEmpty())%2520%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509btnSubir.setEnabled(false)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509btnBajar.setEnabled(false)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509btnEliminar.setEnabled(false)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%257D%2520else%2520%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509var%2520index%2520%253D%2520lstFormula.indexOf(lstFormula.getSelection()%255B0%255D)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509btnSubir.setEnabled(index!%253D0)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509btnBajar.setEnabled(index!%253DlstFormula.getChildren().length%2520-%25201)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509btnEliminar.setEnabled(true)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%257D%250D%250A%2509%257D)%253B%250D%250A%2509%250D%250A%2509%250D%250A%2509win.add(new%2520qx.ui.basic.Label(%2522Sort%2520order%2520formulas%253A%2522)%252C%2520%257Bleft%253A%25200%252C%2520top%253A%2520%252261%2525%2522%257D)%253B%250D%250A%2509win.add(lstFormula%252C%2520%257Bleft%253A%25200%252C%2520top%253A%2520%252265%2525%2522%252C%2520right%253A%25200%252C%2520bottom%253A%25200%257D)%253B%250D%250A%2509%250D%250A%2509var%2520tableModel%2520%253D%2520table.getTableModel()%253B%250D%250A%2509%250D%250A%2509for%2520(var%2520x%2520%253D%25200%253B%2520x%2520%253C%2520tableModel.getColumnCount()%253B%2520x%252B%252B)%2520%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509var%2520listItem%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.ListItem(tableModel.getColumnName(x)%252C%2520null%252C%2520x)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509lstCampo.add(listItem)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509tableModel.setColumnSortable(x%252C%2520false)%253B%250D%250A%2509%257D%250D%250A%2509%250D%250A%2509%250D%250A%2509%250D%250A%2509var%2520resultado%2520%253D%2520%255B%255D%253B%250D%250A%2509%250D%250A%2509for%2520(var%2520x%2520in%2520resultado)%2520%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509var%2520listItem%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.ListItem(resultado%255Bx%255D.descrip%252C%2520null%252C%2520resultado%255Bx%255D)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509lstFormula.add(listItem)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250A%2509%2509var%2520btn%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.menu.RadioButton(resultado%255Bx%255D.descrip)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509btn.setUserData(%2522listItem%2522%252C%2520listItem)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509btn.setGroup(radiogroup)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509btn.addListener(%2522execute%2522%252C%2520btn_execute%252C%2520this)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509menuMain.addAt(btn%252C%2520lstFormula.indexOf(listItem))%253B%250D%250A%2509%257D%250D%250A%2509var%2520children%2520%253D%2520menuMain.getChildren()%253B%250D%250A%2509if%2520(children.length%2520%2526%2526%2520children.length%2520%253E%25201)%2520%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509menuMain.addBefore(new%2520qx.ui.menu.Separator()%252C%2520btnEditar)%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509children%255B0%255D.fireEvent(%2522execute%2522)%253B%250D%250A%2509%257D%250D%250A%250D%250A%250D%250A%2509%250D%250A%2509%257D%252C%250D%250A%2509members%2520%253A%2520%250D%250A%2509%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509row1%253A%2520null%252C%250D%250A%2509%2509row2%253A%2520null%252C%250D%250A%2509%2509formula%253A%2520null%252C%250D%250A%2509%2509resultado%253A%2520null%252C%250D%250A%250D%250A%2509%2509functionOrdenamiento%253A%2520function(par1%252C%2520par2)%2520%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509this.row1%2520%253D%2520par1%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509this.row2%2520%253D%2520par2%253B%250D%250A%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509eval(this.formula)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250A%2509%2509%2509return%2520this.resultado%253B%250D%250A%2509%2509%257D%250D%250A%2509%257D%250D%250A%257D)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250A%250D%250A%250D%250A%250D%250A%252F%252F%2520Document%2520is%2520the%2520application%2520root%250D%250Avar%2520doc%2520%253D%2520this.getRoot()%253B%250D%250A%250D%250Avar%2520menutbl%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.menu.Menu()%253B%250D%250A%250D%250A%2509var%2520tableModelSal%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.table.model.Simple()%253B%250D%250A%2509tableModelSal.setColumns(%255B%2522Reparaci%25C3%25B3n%2522%252C%2520%2522Costo%2522%252C%2520%2522Cantidad%2522%252C%2520%2522Total%2522%255D%252C%2520%255B%2522reparacion%2522%252C%2520%2522costo%2522%252C%2520%2522cantidad%2522%252C%2520%2522total%2522%255D)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250A%2509var%2520custom%2520%253D%2520%257BtableColumnModel%2520%253A%2520function(obj)%2520%257B%250D%250A%2509%2509return%2520new%2520qx.ui.table.columnmodel.Resize(obj)%253B%250D%250A%2509%257D%257D%253B%250D%250A%2509%250D%250A%2509var%2520tblSal%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.table.Table(tableModelSal%252C%2520custom)%253B%250D%250A%2509%252F%252FtblTotales.toggleShowCellFocusIndicator()%253B%250D%250A%2509tblSal.setShowCellFocusIndicator(false)%253B%250D%250A%2509tblSal.toggleColumnVisibilityButtonVisible()%253B%250D%250A%2509tblSal.toggleStatusBarVisible()%253B%250D%250A%2509tblSal.setContextMenu(menutbl)%253B%250D%250A%2509%250D%250A%2509%250D%250A%2509var%2520tableColumnModelSal%2520%253D%2520tblSal.getTableColumnModel()%253B%250D%250A%250D%250A%2509var%2520selectionModelSal%2520%253D%2520tblSal.getSelectionModel()%253B%250D%250A%2509selectionModelSal.setSelectionMode(qx.ui.table.selection.Model.SINGLE_SELECTION)%253B%250D%250A%2509selectionModelSal.addListener(%2522changeSelection%2522%252C%2520function(e)%257B%250D%250A%250D%250A%2509%257D)%253B%250D%250A%2509%250D%250A%2509doc.add(tblSal%252C%2520%257Bleft%253A%25200%252C%2520top%253A%25200%252C%2520right%253A%25200%252C%2520bottom%253A%25200%257D)%253B%250D%250A%2509%250D%250A%2509var%2520a%2520%253D%2520%255B%250D%250A%2509%2509%257Breparacion%253A%2520%2522repa%252001%2522%252C%2520costo%253A%252013%252C%2520cantidad%253A%25200%252C%2520total%253A%25200%257D%252C%250D%250A%2509%2509%257Breparacion%253A%2520%2522repa%252002%2522%252C%2520costo%253A%252012%252C%2520cantidad%253A%25200%252C%2520total%253A%25200%257D%252C%250D%250A%2509%2509%257Breparacion%253A%2520%2522repa%252003%2522%252C%2520costo%253A%252011%252C%2520cantidad%253A%25200%252C%2520total%253A%25200%257D%252C%250D%250A%2509%2509%257Breparacion%253A%2520%2522repa%252004%2522%252C%2520costo%253A%252010%252C%2520cantidad%253A%25200%252C%2520total%253A%25200%257D%252C%250D%250A%2509%2509%257Breparacion%253A%2520%2522repa%252005%2522%252C%2520costo%253A%25209%252C%2520cantidad%253A%25200%252C%2520total%253A%25200%257D%252C%250D%250A%2509%2509%257Breparacion%253A%2520%2522repa%252006%2522%252C%2520costo%253A%25208%252C%2520cantidad%253A%25200%252C%2520total%253A%25200%257D%252C%250D%250A%2509%2509%257Breparacion%253A%2520%2522repa%252007%2522%252C%2520costo%253A%25207%252C%2520cantidad%253A%25200%252C%2520total%253A%25200%257D%252C%250D%250A%2509%2509%257Breparacion%253A%2520%2522repa%252008%2522%252C%2520costo%253A%25206%252C%2520cantidad%253A%25200%252C%2520total%253A%25200%257D%252C%250D%250A%2509%2509%257Breparacion%253A%2520%2522repa%252009%2522%252C%2520costo%253A%25205%252C%2520cantidad%253A%25200%252C%2520total%253A%25200%257D%252C%250D%250A%2509%2509%257Breparacion%253A%2520%2522repa%252010%2522%252C%2520costo%253A%25204%252C%2520cantidad%253A%25200%252C%2520total%253A%25200%257D%252C%250D%250A%2509%2509%257Breparacion%253A%2520%2522repa%252011%2522%252C%2520costo%253A%25203%252C%2520cantidad%253A%25200%252C%2520total%253A%25200%257D%252C%250D%250A%2509%2509%257Breparacion%253A%2520%2522repa%252012%2522%252C%2520costo%253A%25202%252C%2520cantidad%253A%25200%252C%2520total%253A%25200%257D%252C%250D%250A%2509%2509%257Breparacion%253A%2520%2522repa%252013%2522%252C%2520costo%253A%25201%252C%2520cantidad%253A%25200%252C%2520total%253A%25200%257D%250D%250A%2509%255D%253B%250D%250A%2509tableModelSal.setDataAsMapArray(a%252C%2520true)%253B%250D%250A%250D%250A%250D%250Amenutbl.add(new%2520prueba.menubuttonOrdenamiento(tblSal%252C%2520%2522pageProductos%2522))%253B%22%2C%20%22mode%22%3A%22ria%22%7D)